# Configure KVM/QEMU with TLS?

Tags: kvm, virtualization, qemu, tls, spice

New to virtualization and kvm and I have a problem when i try to create a virtual machine with spice:

virt-install --name Windows-7-x64 --ram 2048 --disk path=~/kvm/images/win7.img,size=50 --vcpus=1 --os-type windows --os-variant=win7 --graphics spice,port=5900,listen=0.0.0.0,password=test --video qxl --cdrom ~/Downloads/en_windows_7_professional_with_sp1_x64_dvd_u_676939.iso

`ERROR    unsupported configuration: Auto allocation of spice TLS port     requested but spice TLS is disabled in qemu.conf`

I would assume that TLS have to be configured somehow but after having a look at qemu and uncommenting the lines for spice:

`spice_tls = 1
 spice_tls_x509_cert_dir = "/etc/pki/libvirt-spice`

Not sure how to configure TLS ??

Just a brief scenario i am trying to setup vm's on KVM with spice and access them from another computer whether it's linux or windows from virt-viewer.

A quick question as well how secure that connection over a LAN or WAN.

Thanks any help is appreciated.

**Update**:

I got around the problem by disabling the port 5900 then edit it in the template after the installation from this post:
[How to create KVM guest with SPICE graphics but TLS disabled using virt-install?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148794/how-to-create-kvm-guest-with-spice-graphics-but-tls-disabled-using-virt-install)

But i still believe that the connection is not over TLS so i would appreciate if someone explain this process.

Hint: For Centos users i could not connect to KVM from another machine with spice viewer until i opened port 5900 on the server through firewalld [Centos 7] or iptables [Centos 6] even if selinux is disabled.

Comment: Regarding the problem that you cannot connect from extern: Did you set `spice_listen` in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` to anything else than the loopback IP? Check where the process listens to using `netstat -ltnp`.

Comment: Why do you want TLS? Spice is an encrypted protocol with built in per channel encryption

Comment: @ManuelFaux Yes in the config file spice is listening to all public interfaces. Still didn't work until i opened a port in Centos firewall manually.

Comment: @dyasny That was one of my questions is that connection is secure enough over LAN and especially WAN and for extra security and curiosity as well.

Comment: @Mario: Sorry, I didn't recognize the word *unit*... Anyway, why is it astonishing that you need to open the firewall to allow incoming spice connections? That's what I expect from a firewall, to block all incoming connections which were not explicitly allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned the 'cert key'  used in tls encryption,
I think you are using the 'plain spice' channel.
And your are right , it is insecure, 
especially the 'input channel' can be risky if someone type 'password or credit card number' via spice console.

To encrypt with tls-spice,
you need

- Create a cert, deploy the private-key part on server, and deploy the
  public-key part on client.
- Edit the libvirt domain to instruct that 'all spice spice go through tls'.
  You can reference detail steps at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaat/liaatsecspice.htm.

And to your another question -- "A quick question as well how secure that connection over a LAN or WAN." ,
yes there is alternatives.

For example, 'ssh tunnel' is  always an option in such scenario.

You can let qemu/spice only bind on 127.0.0.1, say 127.0.0.1:5900.
On client,

first  'ssh -L 9000:127.0.0.1:5900 ${server}'  to establish ssh tunnel,

then   spicy -h 127.0.0.1 -p 9000  to connect spice via  ssh tunnel.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and Thanks that's exactly what i wanted to know ... i am pretty much not an expert in networking and linux world but still in the learning phase ... so this information was very helpful for me and after a bit of google search everything start to sync. Next step is to deploy the configuration and hopefully will work on my small home lab. Just a thing that is a bit frustrating while you learn there is no centralized place for a good documentation about KVM for me till now.

Comment: "there is no centralized place for a good documentation about KVM"

You are right, no centralized good documentation about KVM.

KVM (more precisely, kvm/qemu/spice) is VM, and VM is just like normal computer,composed by many parts. 

Actually, here is very rough mapping

'kvm'  --  cpu/memory

'qemu' -- motherboard, devices (Disk, network card)

'spice' -- display, especially optimized for the 'qxl virtual video card'.

Since there is  no centralized place for a good documentation about computer,
so does KVM. :)